# glmmLasso Error Message "Error in blockstand(X, ipen.which, inotpen.which)"

Tags: r

I have been stuck on this error for a week now! I am modeling the effects of urbanization on nest predation, and cannot figure out what this error means. I have a large set of predictor variables, and so am using LASSOs as my variable selection process. I have two response variables: Whether or not a nest was predated, and how long it took to be predated. I have run the first model predicting predation, and had no issues. I then swapped out my response variable and changed the family to poisson, and now it gives me this error when I run the glmmLasso function which is imbedded in the for loop CV process:

glmmLasso code that gives error:

```
glmmLasso(Days_Surv~
                    as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Grazed) + as.factor(X1M_Veg_Density) + 
                    as.factor(X5M_Veg_Density) +  
                    Dist_Build + Dist_Road + Build_area_RHR + Build_area_500 + Build_area_100 +
                    DEV_RHR + NAT_RHR + AG_RHR + DEV_500 + NAT_500 + AG_500 + DEV_100 +
                    NAT_100 + AG_100 + Road_Length_RHR + Road_Length_500 + Road_Length_100 +
                    Avg_1M_Veg_Height + Avg_5M_Veg_Height, rnd = list(Site=~1),
                    family = lasso.fam, data = surv.train, 
                    lambda=lambda[j],switch.NR=F,final.re=FALSE,
                    control=list(start=Delta.start,q_start=Q.start))
```

And the error message:

```
Error in blockstand(X, ipen.which, inotpen.which) : 
  Block belonging to columns 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 has not full rank!
```

The full code I am running for the lamba tuning is:

```
set.seed(1992)
N<-dim(prednests_month)[1]
ind<-sample(N,N)
#lambda <- seq(100,0,by=-1)
lambda <- seq(100,0,length.out = 100)
kk<-5
nk <- floor(N/kk)

Devianz_ma<-matrix(Inf,ncol=kk,nrow=length(lambda))

Icept <- log(mean(prednests_month$Days_Surv))
Delta.start <- c(Icept,rep(0,24+1+1+2+7+7+35))  the random intercept factor)
Q.start <- 0.1 
lasso.fam <- poisson(link = log)
## ---

for(j in 1:length(lambda))
{
  print(paste("Iteration ", j,sep=""))
  
  for (i in 1:kk)
  {
    if (i < kk)
    {
      indi <- ind[(i-1)*nk+(1:nk)]
    }else{
      indi <- ind[((i-1)*nk+1):N]
    }
    
    surv.train<-prednests_week[-indi,]
    surv.test<-prednests_week[indi,]
    
    glm2 <- try(glmmLasso(Days_Surv~
                            as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Grazed) + as.factor(X1M_Veg_Density) + 
                            as.factor(X5M_Veg_Density) +  
                            Dist_Build + Dist_Road + Build_area_RHR + Build_area_500 + Build_area_100 +
                            DEV_RHR + NAT_RHR + AG_RHR + DEV_500 + NAT_500 + AG_500 + DEV_100 +
                            NAT_100 + AG_100 + Road_Length_RHR + Road_Length_500 + Road_Length_100 +
                            Avg_1M_Veg_Height + Avg_5M_Veg_Height, rnd = list(Site=~1),
                          family = lasso.fam, data = surv.train, 
                          lambda=lambda[j],switch.NR=F,final.re=FALSE,
                          control=list(start=Delta.start,q_start=Q.start))
                          ,silent=TRUE) 
    
    
    if(class(glm2)!="try-error")
    {  
      # print non-zero coefs to monitor the fitting process
      print(names(glm2$coefficients[glm2$coefficients!=0]))
      
      y.hat<-predict(glm2,surv.test)    
      
      Devianz_ma[j,i]<-sum(lasso.fam$dev.resids(surv.test$Days_Surv,y.hat,wt=rep(1,length(y.hat))))
    }
  }
  print(sum(Devianz_ma[j,]))
}

Devianz_vec<-apply(Devianz_ma,1,sum)
opt2<-which.min(Devianz_vec)


Surv_Lasso_cv<- glmmLasso(Days_Surv~
                            as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Grazed) + as.factor(X1M_Veg_Density) + as.factor(X5M_Veg_Density) +  
                            Dist_Build + Dist_Road + Build_num_RHR + Build_num_500 +
                            Build_num_100 + Build_area_RHR + Build_area_500 + Build_area_100 +
                            DEV_RHR + NAT_RHR + AG_RHR + DEV_500 + NAT_500 + AG_500 + DEV_100 +
                            NAT_100 + AG_100 + Road_Length_RHR + Road_Length_500 + Road_Length_100 +
                            Avg_1M_Veg_Height + Avg_5M_Veg_Height, rnd = list(Site=~1), 
                          family = poisson(link = log), data = prednests_week, 
                          lambda=lambda[opt2],switch.NR=F,final.re=TRUE,
                          control=list(start=Delta.start,q_start=Q.start))

summary(Surv_Lasso_cv)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have been unable to find anything helpful about this error message.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Try to remove some of the factor variables from your fomular. I solved my issue because some of factor are correlated with the random effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).